# Perform substitution in a substitution file with autotools

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

I have tried to look around and cannot seem to find the correct information. I would like to substitute @srcdir@ in a file used by AC_SUBST_FILE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AC_OUTPUT` doesn't allow you two substitution steps, so I don't think that's possible. However, you could do something like this:

my_substitution_file:

```
srcdir is %srcdir%
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_PROG_SED
file=my_substitution_file
AC_SUBST_FILE([file])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([my_file.in])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am:

```
my_file: my_file.in Makefile
    $(AM_V_GEN)$(SED) -e s,%srcdir%,$(srcdir), <$< >$@
```

my_file.in.in:

```
Here is what my_substitution_file has to say: @file@
```

All together, this should result in a file called my_file with the contents:

```
Here is what my_substitution_file has to say: srcdir is /path/to/your/source
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the work around. I didn't think the double substitution in one shot was valid but figured I hadn't been the first to try it.